# C++ error says class not declared

Tags: c++

I was practicing my c++ in a compiler and i solved all the errors but this one. it says my class isnt declared. i didnt even declare the first class I had.

```
  // Example program
  #include <iostream>
  #include <string>
  using namespace std;

  class Enemy{
private:
int attack = 0,
block = 0;

public:
void chargedAttack(){
    cout << "Get Ready!";
    }
void spinningAttack(){
    cout << "How bout this!";
    }
};

 class minion::Enemy{
public:
    int specialAttack(int x){
    int attackPower = x;
    cout << "Take this you chump! " << attackPower + 6; 
    }
 };


 int main()
 {
  minion chump1;
  chump1.spinningAttack();

 }
```

This is the error message: 21:7: error: 'minion' has not been declared
21:20: error: expected unqualified-id before '{' token

Comment: In "class minion::Enemy" there is one colon too much.

Comment: Why are you having void spinningAttack(){
    cout << "How bout this!";
    }
}; instead of void spinningAttack(){
    cout << "How bout this!";
    }
}

Comment: Then this class minion::Enemy{
public:
    int specialAttack(int x){
    int attackPower = x;
    cout << "Take this you chump! " << attackPower + 6; 
    }
 }; replace with class minion::Enemy{
public:
    int specialAttack(int x){
    int attackPower = x;
    cout << "Take this you chump! " << attackPower + 6; 
    }
 }

Comment: Start with indenting your code. Also read [this](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/basics-of-inheritance#how-to-code-inherit).

Comment: Simple syntax error( Correct: `class minion: public Enemy {`

Comment: @JosephMwema can you clarify what you mean. I dont see a difference in your wording. i see a semi colon at the end though. please clarify

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem you have is in your `minion` class:

```
class minion::Enemy{
public:
    int specialAttack(int x)
    {
        int attackPower = x;
        cout << "Take this you chump! " << attackPower + 6; 
    }
};
```

In order to declare a child class, it needs to have to following syntax:

```
class ChildClass : public ParentClass
{
    // Declare variable and/or functions
};
```

You are confusing the syntax for implementing a function outside of its class with declaring a new class. You can implement functions outside of their class like:

```
void AnyClassFunction::AnyClass {
```

However, you cannot use the same syntax to declare a child class. You should change the header line of your `minion` class to:

```
class minion : public Enemy{ // This tells the compiler that the minion class is inherited from the Enemy class
public:
    int specialAttack(int x)
    {
        int attackPower = x;
        cout << "Take this you chump! " << attackPower + 6; 
    }
};
```